# Phing syntax error on exec using "less than" character

Tags: xml, linux, phing

I am having problems with malformed XML in my phing build file.  I want to have a task that will gunzip a file and then pipe it to mysql to restore a database backup.  I have found that having the "<" symbol in the command causes errors.

Here is my current line that is breaking the build script:

```
<exec command="gunzip < ${mysql.backup} | mysql -u ${mysql.username} -p ${mysql.password} ${mysql.database}"
            logoutput="true" checkreturn="true" />
```

Output:

```
BUILD FAILED
exception 'BuildException' with message 'Error reading project file [wrapped: /home/ec2-user/project/build.xml:206:30: > required]' in /usr/share/pear/phing/parser/ProjectConfigurator.php:197
```

Is there someway to escape the `command=""` part?

Or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Less than signs not starting elements should be escaped; using `&lt;` is the easiest way to do this in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if that was how to do it in phing/xml, but it worked!